# How to fix Canon EOS 1200D flash release hook making a click click click?

Tags: canon, flash, sensor, camera-settings

My Canon EOS 1200D was working ok until, suddenly, it stopped showing the display.

People suggested to take out the SD CARD and BATTERY for some time. This was done. Now any activity on my part, whether it is plugging in the lens, or changing the setting, the flash opens up and starts click click click ... and then stops.

My next move will start this clicking again. It is not flashing, but the flash release hook just goes back and forth. I can push this hook forward and the clicking stops; but it would start again later. Please help.

What is this new problem? For any setting on the round knob this is happening. Can I ever have my normal camera back?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the camera needs to be replaced. It might be possible to have it serviced/repaired, but it will likely cost as much as replacing it with an excellent condition used one (or more).

Comment: But I have no problem in taking pictures. The display is coming and pictures are perfect. Only botheration is that any action on my part in changing the setting triggers a click click for 2 to 3 seconds.